# Mean of column varies based

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have some code that calculates the column mean of all values greater than or equal to zero. For some reason I get a different output when I start from the back with .iloc[-1:] than if I just do the whole column or start somewhere else.

```
dtest = {'col1': [1, -2, -1, -1, -5], 'col2': [3, 4, -2, -1, -5]}
dftest = pd.DataFrame(data=dtest)
dftest

dftest[dftest['col2'] >= 0].iloc[-1:].mean().values[1]
```

When I run this code I get a  mean of 4.0

But when I run this code with iloc[:]

```
dftest[dftest['col2'] >= 0].iloc[:].mean().values[1]
```

I get 3.5

and iloc[-2:] or [0:] or [-0:] also gives me 3.5.

Why does it differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dftest[dftest['col2'] >= 0].iloc[-1:].mean().values[1]
```

In the above code, when you use the filter `[dftest['col2'] >= 0]`, the filtered dataframe contains the first 2 elements, i.e, the positive integers, 3 and 4. when youd do `iloc[-1:]`, it selects the last element that is 4. when you take the mean of the single element, you get 4 as result

In the case where you use `iloc[:]` instead of `iloc[-1:]`, you select all the elements, that is, 3 and 4, giving their mean equal to 3.5

It is important to understand indexing with negative integers. They will pick the last n number of elements when using indexing like `[-n:]`

When you do `iloc[-2:0]`, you select the last 2 elements (3 and 4). `iloc[0:]` is same as `iloc[-0:]`, since -0 is also 0, and it selects all the items from index 0 to end of series, i.e, 3 and 4 both

Answer (score 1):

Like Yati said, the indexer [-1:] won't do the trick. To begin from the back, it would look something like this:

```
dftest[dftest['col2'] >= 0].iloc[::-1].mean().values[1]
#--or--
dftest['col2'][dftest['col2'] >= 0].iloc[::-1].mean()
```

Which does give an average of 3.5.